# How to create a rotating wheel with images in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi I have ferris wheel graphic.  It has 10 elements that forms a big circle (like a ferris wheel). I want to rotate the circle with 8 `<div>`s.
How can I do that in javascript or HTML5?

Something like [this](http://jsdo.it/proppy/plUk).
But I need the pink to be a `<div>` area so that I can put image on it.
Any suggestions&help are very much appreciated.

Comment: Perish wheel? You mean ferris wheel?

Comment: Do have any experienced  doing it?

Answer (score 2):

Here's an [**example**](http://jsfiddle.net/8BqwH/2). Using a fairly cross-browser approach.

```
var rotation = 0
setInterval(function() {
    $('div').css({
        "-moz-transform": "rotate(" + rotation + "deg)",
        "-webkit-transform": "rotate(" + rotation + "deg)",
        "-o-transform": "rotate(" + rotation + "deg)",
        "-ms-transform": "rotate(" + rotation + "deg)"
    });

    rotation = (rotation + 10) % 361
}, 200)
```

Answer (score 1):

Very similar to IAbstractDownvoteFactory's, but all CSS. I wrote it for webkit browsers, getting the others to work should be evident but will require a lot of copy-paste.

```
.rotate-me {
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 8s;
    -webkit-animation-name: rotate;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
    0% {-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);}
    100% {-webkit-transform: rotate(359deg);}
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/t2fEW/

Comment: It totally works, at least in Chrome 22. It obviously won't work outside of webkit.

Comment: It's a shame this is downvoted at all. I upvoted. It's clearly labeled and functional and helpful within those parameters.